# Upgrading Eclipse 3.6.1 to eclipse 4.3.1

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, upgrade, eclipse-kepler

I'm trying to update my project from  **Eclipse 3.6 to eclipse 4.3.1** .I downloaded the latest eclipse and followed the "File->Import->install->from existing installation" method to 
get the configuration from my existing eclipse installation.Everything is fine except one thing, Some of the imports having starting with this "**import org.eclipse.ui.internal.x;**"
are showing errors.

When I searched for the package "org.eclipse.ui.internal" , I found that it exists in the jar 
**"org.eclipse.ui.workbench_3.105.1.v-20130821-1411.jar"** .
Any idea what to do , is there a possibility that I 've to manually update this jar and if that's the case is how to do that?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Please stop posting that bad advice, especially if the method of getting a recent Eclipse version has nothing to do at all with the problem described by the poster. Exactly the same issue will happen if he installs from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

Classes in packages with `internal` in the name are internal to Eclipse and are not part of the API (see [Eclipse API Rules of Engagement](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-API-Use/index.html)). As such they are subject to change without notice. It may be that the classes you use no longer exist as Eclipse 4 internals have been substantially rewritten.

Comment: so u mean there's no backward compatibility or there is backward compatibility but I've to search which classes are now providing the functionalities which I need? And how can I search for that any suggetions?

Comment: There is backward compatibility for the official API but not for internal classes. Some classes may have gone, others may have moved or changed name. What classes are you missing?

Comment: THESE ARE SOME OF THE CLASSES :                                                                                                              
                                                                        import org.eclipse.ui.internal.ContainerPlaceholder;                     import org.eclipse.ui.internal.ILayoutContainer;
import org.eclipse.ui.internal.LayoutPart;
import org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartPlaceholder;
import org.eclipse.ui.internal.Perspective;
import org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewSashContainer;
import org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewStack;

Comment: All classes to do with view and editor layout, perspectives, stacks and the like have been completely replaced with entirely new code based on the e4 application model.

Comment: I've heard of something called as compatibility layer can I make use of that somehow , to avoid rewriting the code .I don't have much idea about it.Please tell??

Comment: The compatibility layer provides the old 3.x interfaces in Eclipse 4, but this only applies to official APIs not to internal classes.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that the classes you mention are no longer in the IDE implementation, they've been replaced with a modeled UI. If you want to get a feel for how the new IDE works I'd recommend the 'e4' tutorials from Lars Vogel.

You may actually find that the new mechanisms are easier to work with and the model is all API (so we'll support going forward...